# Yii Framework - Rights extension doesnt seem to work properly

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am new in **Yii 1** Framework and I am trying to work with Rights extension (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/) in a project (it is mandatory to use Rights extension in this project because others projects where built in using it).

I set up Right correctly and it is working on **localhost/site?r=rights**

I had all necessary tables:

*authassignment*,

*authitem*,

*authitemchild*,

*rights*,

**user** with *(id, username, password)* where I could add a Admin (superuser) and AnotherUser.

[image]

=====>
**So, What is my problem?**
<=====

Once I have generated **Permissions** based on my **Models**:

[image]

And assigning which **permissions** my **AnotherUser** could have:

[image]

It seems that nothing happened, because my **AnotherUser** can access all the others methods, such as **User.Delete** and **User.Update**.

I am only managing user access throught the **Rights Interface.**

Is there a set up in the code as well?

I tried to **extends** all my **controllers** from **RController**. (the Controller that Rights extends as well)

I added the 'rights' in the filters:

```
    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
            'rights',
        );
    }
```

And I didn't modify the controller:

```
     /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Thank you in advance if you could help me in this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve partially my own problem:

1. Generate all **Permissions** that you want:

***Generate items for controller actions***

It will display in the Operations. (list, view, create, update, delete, admin)

2. Create **Tasks** adding Childs from Operations
3. Create **Roles** adding Childs from Tasks.
4. Assing *Roles, Tasks or Operations* to an user.

*Assing* and *Revoke* Roles, Tasks or Operations as you wish.